# command for spliting a chapter from a book in pdf format

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I  want to split from page 365 to 432 ( a chapter) from my  Calculus (27 mb) book and send it to some one as a single pdf file. What command I should write in Terminal to split  ? I am using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming the book is also a PDF...
Install pdftk an then do the following (whereas in.pdf is your input document and out1.pdf will be the isolated chapter):

> pdftk in.pdf cat 365-432 output out1.pdf

Comment: how to install pdftk?

Comment: Like with any other tool that's in the repos: sudo apt-get install pdftk
(I think it's in the repos, but I can't check it right now... should be though...)

Comment: I just double checked: pdftk is in the repos! So sudo apt-get install pdftk will work!

Answer (score 1):

Install xpdf by downloading it from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/xpdf). Download the .deb file and open it with Ubuntu software centre and install it. and then from command line `pdftops 100p-inputfile.pdf - | psselect -starting page number-ending page number | \
         ps2pdf14 - anyname.pdf`